# Creating Custom CSS To Override Default CSS

Tags: html, css

First time here, and was hoping that someone would be able to help with an issue I’ve been dealing with. I’ve had specific details not to modify the original CSS, and instead told to create a new CSS that contains specific overrides for the original CSS. How would I go about doing that efficiently?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should give examples on what you're working with because your issue may be caused by different factors

Comment: Please add some code you've tried. This is a very easy thing to research. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 2):

css are applied is a given order. Here are few examples

**Case 1: overide default color for a div**

```
div#foo {
  color: blue; /* This one is applied to <div id="foo"></div> */
}

div {
  color: red;
}
```

**Case 2:  css which is loaded at last will be on top.**

```
div {
  color: red;
}

div {
  color: blue; /* This one is applied to <div id="foo"></div> */
}
```

**case 3: important takes first place**

```
div {
  color: red !important;
}
```

**case 4: multiple important**

```
div {
  color: red !important;
}

div {
  color: yellow !important;  /* This will be applied */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include your css file after original css file. Add your custom class in html and use it to override original code.

Don't use !important property it create issue in responsive style.